# How to open a file with a already defined path

Tags: vbscript, path

So the code works so far but When I try to open a txt file with the path found by the function it won't open the txt file. Error message : object doesn't support this property or method.

```
 Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function GetFilePath(FileName)
Dim strScriptPath
strScriptPath = objFSO.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.ParentFolder.ParentFolder.Path
GetFilePath = (strScriptPath & "\" & FileName & ".txt")
wscript.echo GetFilePath
End Function

GetFilePath("ApprovedShares")

'Reads Approvedshare txt and makes the txt file into an array
Dim objApprovedFile, StrApprovedPath
StrApprovedPath = ("" & GetFilePath("ApprovedShares") & "")
wscript.echo StrApprovedPath 
objApprovedFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (StrApprovedPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Set` to assign an object to a variable:

```
Set objApprovedFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (StrApprovedPath)
```

On second thought:

You need less () and more """":

```
StrApprovedPath = ("" & GetFilePath("ApprovedShares") & "")
```

==>

```
StrApprovedPath = """" & GetFilePath("ApprovedShares") & """"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response